# Where can I hide my SSID and password protect it in AirPort Express?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard

For school I have to configure my airport express to their requirements, I know how to disable DHCP on my mac, but from there how do I hide my SSID and password protect it?

Comment: While I agree that in almost any situation a wireless access point should be password encrypted (using WPA2 & AES for 802.11n if you want to get "n" throughput), whomever at your school is recommending that you hide the SSID is deluding themselves. Here's a link that was posted in another question here about SSID hiding: http://blogs.technet.com/b/steriley/archive/2007/10/16/myth-vs-reality-wireless-ssids.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the settings on an Airport (Express, Extreme, etc.) you need to open Airport Utility in your Utilities folder.

You can either use the "wizard" by just clicking on your Airport Express and then pressing Continue and following the steps or you can click Manual Setup and go to the Airport section, click on the Wireless tab and then click on "Wireless Network Options..." to create a "Closed" (hidden) network. See the following screenshots (both of these are using Manual Setup):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the AirPort Admin Utility, there should be an option called: Create a closed network" this option should lets you disable SSID broadcasting.